# Detectar si apunto a un server local sql o en la red

Tags: c#, sql

El problema está en la detección de si un server sql es local o no, tengo una apk que hace salva y restaura, pero a la hora de configurar la conexión al sql necesito que la apk detecte que el server que apunta es local, ya que posee 2 funciones distintas si es local o no, trate con un `if` pero imagínense, es increíble la de variantes para poner un server local en una configuración. Tengo solo esto en la condicional

```
IF(ServerName.Text == "Localhost" ||  ServerName.Text == "." || ServerName.Text == "(local)")
{
     Ejecuta codigo

}
else
{
    Ejecuta este codigo entonces
}
```

Disculpen a lo mejor la pregunta se responde facil,pero simplemente no doy con lo que es
Gracias por su respuesta con antelacion.

Comment: desde un apk, podrias apuntar a un sqlite o una api que se conecte a una base externa del telefono. cual de las dos estas queriendo hacer?

Comment: y tu server local lo manejas cuando estas compilando y codificando el apk?

Comment: Si creo que es mejor la variante de preguntarle al usuario si su server es local o no y de hay ejecutar las variantes. la cosa es que para hacer una salva desde un server externo necesitarias compartir una carpeta desde la maquina que vas a hacerla y como son muchas personas entonces la carpeta se comprate desde el server con un nombre fijo y en caso de externo entonces hago la salva hacia esa carpeta y luego la copio para la maquina que le pidió la salva, en caso de local entonces solo hago la salva y ya esta.